# PHP how to access $Instance variables from other scripts? (Ratchet)

Tags: php, ratchet

I have a PHP script with a static Instance property (A Ratchet WebSocket controller) and I want to access that instance of a script from another script how would I do that?
(The following code produces a new $Instance of that class not the original one)

(I want to achieve this so I can access the clients list from the WebSocket controller)

(I'm following this tutorial: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world)

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
<?php
    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    require '/var/www/html/test/src/Chat.php';
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
    
  $obj = MyApp\Chat::getInstance(); 
  var_dump($obj);
  foreach ($obj->clients as $client) {
    var_dump($client);
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

/src/Chat.php

```
<?php
namespace MyApp;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    public static $instance = null;
    
    public $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
      if (self::$instance == null)
      {
        self::$instance = new Chat();
      }
   
      return self::$instance;
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        $numRecv = count($this->clients) - 1;
        echo sprintf('Connection %d sending message "%s" to %d other connection%s' . "\n"
            , $from->resourceId, $msg, $numRecv, $numRecv == 1 ? '' : 's');

        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                // The sender is not the receiver, send to each client connected
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // The connection is closed, remove it, as we can no longer send it messages
        $this->clients->detach($conn);

        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";

        $conn->close();
    }
}
?>
```

/bin/chat-server.php

```
<?php
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
?>
```

composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyApp\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "^0.4.3"
    }
}
```

Comment: You showed us some code which ***should*** work, but don't mention what problem you get. Please update your question with more details. what is *that instance* in your case?

Comment: @biesior Updated...

Comment: It would to be better assign instance to variable in your index.php like `$obj = MyApp\Chat::getInstance()`, `var_dump($obj)`, `foreach($obj->clients...)`

Comment: @biesior I updated the code but that doesn't fix the issue at hand...